# How to reimport only ONE maven dependency in IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Idea allows me to reimport all dependencies but since I work on a huge project, reimporting all dependencies takes lot of time. 
I need only one (lets call it "core-lib") be updated since it's snapshot version.
Thoughts?

Comment: IntelliJ is smart enough to refresh the libraries AFAIK.

Comment: That's if auto-import is turned on...

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` -> Project Settings -> Maven -> Importing

Then turn on *Import Maven Projects Automatically*.

P.S. There is also a right-click option to `Reimport` any maven submodule in the `Maven Projects` pange - did you try that?

Comment: No that's not the same what I asked. I need only one jar to be reimported since idea's reimport includes reimports all of jars and that takes too much time.

Comment: Idea's auto reimport feature only reimports the needed jars when I run it. Perhaps you are using it in the wrong way?

Comment: Lets image there is Project A depends on Project B. The flow: 1. Open IDEA Project A; 2. Build via Maven project B. 3. I need refresh only jars related to project B (that has been deployed to artifactory) and I DON'T want there were previous versions in classpath and I DON'T want to do Maven->Reimport. So actually that was my question

Answer (score 0):

What works for me are the following:

1. Enable auto-import on project. You can do this when importing the project for the first time 
   [image]
   or, opening the project and editing the pom a reminder will pop-up (see below).
   [image]
2. Edit your pom.xml and cut the select dependency you want to re-import.
3. Go to the .m2 folder (usually in ~/.m2) and remove the downloaded jar for the dependency in step 2.
4. Paste back to the pom.mxl the dependency you removed in step 2. This should trigger a re-import of the dependency and download again an updated jar file to your .m2 folder.